# How to center button in horizonatal stackview?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I have a horizontal stackview with two buttons. Now I want, if one button is hidden other should be in the center.

like,

```
[x   x]
[  x  ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the distribution attribute of the UIStackView to **Fill Equally** either from storyboard or programatically:

```
stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
```

Once a button is hidden, the other will be centered.

Answer (score 1):

How about using some hidden UIViews?

- Declare the stackView in your class:

  ```
  var myFirstStack: UIStackView!
  var bool = true
  ```

`bool` is a boolean that is going to simulate the condition when you'd want to hide or show the button.

- Initialize the stackView in `viewDidLoad`:

  ```
  myStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: createButtons("1", "2"))
  let v1 = UIView()
  v1.isHidden = true
  let v2 = UIView()
  v2.isHidden = true
  myStack.insertArrangedSubview(v1, at: 1)
  myStack.addArrangedSubview(v2)
  myStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  myStack.axis = .horizontal
  myStack.spacing = 20
  myStack.distribution = .fillEqually

  view.addSubview(myStack)
  ```

It uses this function:

```
func createButtons(_ named: String...) -> [UIButton] {
    var i = true
    return named.map { name in
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        btn.setTitle(name, for: .normal)
        btn.backgroundColor = i ? .yellow : .red
        i.toggle()
        btn.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        return btn
    }
}
```

- Add the autolayout constraints:

  ```
  myFirstStack.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
  myFirstStack.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
  myFirstStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
  myFirstStack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
  ```

Here is what it looks like so far:

[image: 2 buttons]

- When a third button is hit, the UIViews are hidden or shown:

  ```
  @IBAction func hide(_ sender: Any) {
      myFirstStack.arrangedSubviews[0].isHidden = bool  //This is the button to hide
      myFirstStack.spacing = bool ? -100 : 20           //Adjust the spacing to your liking 
      myFirstStack.arrangedSubviews[1].isHidden = !bool //Hide or show the first UIView
      myFirstStack.arrangedSubviews[3].isHidden = !bool //Hide or show the second UIView
      bool.toggle()
  }
  ```

And here is the result:

[image: one button]